# Example of/documention for OpenERP wiki module

Tags: openerp

I am evaluating the [OpenERP wiki module](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/features/wiki.html) (wiki.wiki) The [technical documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/technical_guide/wiki.html) is rather sparse and doesn't actually explain, for example, what the configuration points are or how to publish wiki documents, make them public, etc. Searching the OpenERP site and the web hasn't returned any useful results, and [demo.my.openerp.com](https://demo.my.openerp.com/) doesn't include this module.

Is there a better source for OpenERP documention that I'm missing, or a good example of the OpenERP wiki module in use in the wild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more trawling revealed the same question being asked multiple times on the OpenERP forums, with no response. Fortunately someone has made an attempt to explain the basics of wiki module configuration: [Board index » Users Questions » Installation Questions » Wiki Security](https://web.archive.org/web/20120120002242/http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic16553.html) (web.archive.org)

Comment: The link is redirecting to Odoo's frontpage now. Would be good to update it.

Comment: @KasperSouren good catch, updated with archive.org link - feel free to make edits in such cases